# how to make linux prefer sudo pm-hibernate over systemctl hibernate as default?

Tags: power-management, systemd, hibernate

On installing uswsusp, sudo pm-hibernate works perfectly, but systemctl hibernate does not. How can I make the default hibernate button run the pm-hibernate command?

Comment: I have that same question, but didn't find your question before asking it this way https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079661/another-question-about-hibernate-in-18-04-not-a-duplicate

Comment: @Stewart I have exactly the same problem and haven't found a solution... have you got updates on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem on Ubuntu 18.10. You need to edit the hibernation service :

```
sudo systemctl edit systemd-hibernate.service
```

then paste this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStartPre=-/bin/run-parts -v -a pre /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/s2disk
ExecStartPost=-/bin/run-parts -v --reverse -a post /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep
```

Save, then:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Run `sudo systemctl hibernate` it should work now.

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04. `/usr/sbin/s2disk` doesn't exist