# Hibernate broken except with "pm-hibernate" manual command

Tags: suspend, power-management, hibernate

One of my laptops cannot hibernate properly; when I close the lid or just let it sit for half an hour, I lose the session. The next power-on starts from a fresh boot. This is my son's laptop and he needs it for school. It's a giant pain that he has to start over all the time.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1075860/5786) gives ideas to test:

- `sudo systemctl suspend` works!
- `sudo systemctl hybrid-sleep` works! (from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/781957/5786))
- `sudo systemctl hibernate` seems identical to a power off; the laptop switches off immediately and the next power-on starts from a fresh boot. So the `suspend-then-hibernate` choice is not going to work until I can fix the broken hibernate.
- `systemctl suspend` without sudo does not suspend and I get a message *"user gdm is logged in on nx. Please retry after closing inhibitors [...]"* which is practically Latin to me, but there is a suggestion to use `systemctl suspend -i` which works although I do not understand this.
- `systemctl suspend` without sudo does the same thing; only triggers when adding `-i`. But that is still equivalent to a power off and not a hibernate.
- `sudo pm-hibernate` works exactly as it should! This command is taken from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelHibernate and required me to install `pm-utils`. It is not a solution though; I am not going to ask my son to run a sudo command (and his user account would not have rights anyway).

**So why does `pm-hibernate` work but `systemctl hibernate` does not?** 
And why is there no "suspend" or even "hibernate" in the GUI?? There is only "restart" and "power off".

- Should I just use `hybrid-sleep` instead of hibernate?
- Should I follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1131154/5786) to replace the hibernate with `pm-hibernate`?

---

`/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` contains:

```
HibernateDelaySec=3min
AllowSuspend=yes
AllowHibernation=yes
AllowSuspendThenHibernate=yes
```

`/etc/systemd/logind.conf` contains:

```
HandlePowerKey=suspend
HandleSuspendKey=suspend
HandleHibernateKey=suspend
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
```

In **Settings > Power > Automatic Suspend** the delay is set to 15 minutes. This is the lowest option but I do not know how that correlates to the files listed above. There is no setting for "Hibernate".