# How to make changes in systemd-hibernate.service permanent

Tags: power-management, freeze, systemd, hibernate

Systemctl hibernate is not really working. It freezes when it starts.

I found with this solution:
[how-to-make-linux-prefer-sudo-pm-hibernate-over-systemctl-hibernate-as-default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974788/how-to-make-linux-prefer-sudo-pm-hibernate-over-systemctl-hibernate-as-default/1131154#1131154)

It works great! However, during system update the edit in ***systemctl edit systemd-hibernate.service*** gets undone. Is there a way to make it permanent? Even when I receive update for systemd or kernels etc.?

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: The link I gave describes exactly the same issue I have. By following the solution, I am able to solve the problem (system freeze when it goes into hibernation). It just works all the time, but I have to redo it after a system update. 
I have no idea how I can provide you with more information because the system just freezes. How will I get any data then? So, it would be nice if you also told me how I can provide that information, as I am not a linux guru.